# Variable not saving data in C#

Tags: c#, variables

i've been wondering why my variable is not saving data. this is my code

```
class MainProg
{
  public string name;
  static void Main()
  {
   MainProg m = new MainProg();
   m.Start();
  }
  public void Start()
 {
 Register rs = new Register();
    Register r = (Register)rs;

    r.run();
    Console.WriteLine(name);

 }


}


class Register : MainProg
{
  public void run()
  {
    name = "a";
  }
}
```

Did I forget anything?everytime I try to show the output it shows nothing.Thanks by the way for taking your time.

Comment: check r.name in your console.writeline

Comment: What happens when you step through the code? Does it ever set name?

Comment: Your program doesn't even compile in this form.

Comment: I'm wondering why this code compiles. The variable name is a class member and cannot be accessed in the static context of the method Main.

Comment: @marchemike - Your code still won't compile.  You are using an undeclared variable `name` within the `Register` class.

Comment: marchemike - you are still setting name in one instance and reading it from another - read my answer

Comment: yeah, just found out about it a few minutes ago, that's why it was coming up empty, even if I've placed the variable in the register class.

Comment: It is not good to edit your question when there are answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work.

```
class MainProg
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Register rs = new Register();
        Register r = (Register)rs;

        r.run();
        Console.WriteLine(r.name);
    }

}


class Register : MainProg
{
    public string name;
    public void run()
     {
        name = "a";
     }
}
```

The reason your code fails is that you are creating an instance of Register, which is separate from MainProg even though it inherits from it. You set the variable in the new instance, and then read it from the old.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is an instance field so you need reference of an `object`.

Try,

```
Console.WriteLine(r.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing the name inside the instance of Register called `r` then you print the var name inside the instance of MainProg.

To prove it try:

```
Console.WriteLine(r.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access a member variable inside a static function it will throw an compilation error.

Try to access the variable using object like

```
Console.WriteLine(r.name);
```

Comment: This easily could be a comment.

Comment: Except your statements no longer apply to the question, it was modified by the author, might want to update it.

Comment: @Ramhound: It is not right to edit the question when there are some answers already

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to write the name from this object. The variable you changed is located in the other object 'r'.

Comment: This could easily be a comment.

Comment: Yes but I feel it answers his question. He asked why there is no result, not how to get a result.